# jQuery owl2 remove navigation arrow when there is no item to loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, owl-carousel

I have the following carousel

[image]

I want to disappear the one of the navigation arrows when there are no items on their left/right sides.In screenshot exampe above if i try to use the left arrow it's not looping, because there are no images on the left side, so the arrow should not appear.

Here are the settings i'm currently using

```
Navigation.Defaults = {
    nav: false,
    navRewind: false,
    navText: [ 'prev', 'next' ],
    navSpeed: false,
    navElement: 'div',
    navContainer: false,
    navContainerClass: 'owl2-nav',
    navClass: [ 'owl2-prev', 'owl2-next' ],
    slideBy: 3,
    dotClass: 'owl2-dot',
    dotsClass: 'owl2-dots',
    dots: true,
    dotsEach: false,
    dotData: false,
    dotsSpeed: false,
    dotsContainer: false,
    controlsClass: 'owl2-controls',
    loop: false,
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with the css like below.

```
.owl-nav .owl-prev.disabled,
.owl-nav .owl-next.disabled {
   display: none !important;
}
```

Or you can do that with `js` from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28027976/9695286